# паттерн для input +123 (45) 678-901-234

Tags: html

Помогите написать pattern для input 
 +375 (23) 233-321-421
 такого формата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"\+\d{3}\(\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}"
```

тестируем тут - https://www.regextester.com/?fam=99974

Comment: А как сделать что бы +375 всегда был объязательным

Comment: @Danielqwaqwaqwa  `"\+375\(\d{2}\)\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}"`